# Changing xml node value in SQL with xquery [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-dml

I have example XML in one of the table column:

```
<Root>
   <A>
      <C>c</C>
      <D>d</D>
   </A>
   <B>b</B>
</Root>
```

How can I replace value of A node into something like that:

```
<Root>
   <A>
      <E>e</E>
      <F>f</F>
   </A>
   <B>b</B>
</Root>
```

I tried the following solution

```
DECLARE @var varchar(100);
SET @var = '<E>e</E><F>f</F>'
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Root/A/text())[1] with sql:variable("@var")');
```

but it did not work...

regards

Comment: If this is SQL-Server, then it's not an XQuery Update question but XML Data Modification Language ([XML DML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to use [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx) to replace nodes, only values.
You can use [delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx) and then [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466.aspx) instead.

```
declare @xml as xml = '
<Root>
  <A>
    <C>c</C>
    <D>d</D>
  </A>
  <B>b</B>
</Root>'

declare @var xml
set @var = '<E>e</E><F>f</F>'

set @xml.modify('delete /Root/A/*')
set @xml.modify('insert sql:variable("@var") into (/Root/A)[1]')

select @xml
```